# Run fitnesse test out of MSTest or NUnit or console application in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, fitnesse, fitsharp

I debug `fitnesse` test next way:

1. I run `fitnesse` webserver.
2. Go to test page in browser
3. Run test.
4. `RunnerW.exe` opens.
5. I `ReAttach` to it.
6. I press `Go`.

I want to speed up this cycle.

Is next way possible and how?

E.g.  run `MSTest` or `NUnit` or Console application via F5 from Visual studio. Given I referenced `fit.dll` or `fitsharp.dll` or convert some jar into dll via `IKVM`, configured some runners/parsers, defined paths to saved test pages and test pages names.

Other alternatives to have debug mode with one button click from Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Dzmitry,
please see [here](https://github.com/imanushin/NetRunner/blob/master/execute_regression.ps1) example how to start FitNesse test from Power Shell.

So, answer on your question: execute line:

```
java -jar fitnesse-standalone.jar -c "InternalTests.NetRunnerRegression?suite&format=xml" -b $xmlFilePath
```

Where *InternalTests.NetRunnerRegression?suite&format=xml* is path to your test page, see [documentation](http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.FullReferenceGuide.UserGuide.AdministeringFitNesse.RestfulServices) to check all options available. By this line I started execution test for *InternalTests.NetRunnerRegression* as suite (e.g. this page and subpages), and requested result in xml (html by default).